# Rendering very large amounts of react native text component has low performance

Tags: javascript, react-native, performance

I created a yearly calendar with a very large number of `<Text>` components for every day of that. So rendering for the first time take long time and has poor perf.

[image]

For example, instead, using a simple `<View>` works well.

Is any way to solve the issue?